# Is it possible to modify the contents of a text object using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, object, text

I have a dictionary file called “labels” that contains text objects.

[Screen capture of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX8Kd.png)

When I display the contents of this file, I get the following:

{'175.123.98.240': Text(-0.15349206308126684, -0.6696533109609498, '175.123.98.240'),

'54.66.152.105': Text(-1.0, -0.5455880938500245, '54.66.152.105'),

'62.97.116.82': Text(0.948676253595717, 0.6530664635187481, '62.97.116.82'),

'24.73.75.234': Text(0.849485905682265, -0.778703553136851, '24.73.75.234'),

'1.192.128.23': Text(0.2883091762715677, -0.03432011446968225, '1.192.128.23'),

'183.82.9.19': Text(-0.8855214994079628, 0.7201660238351776, '183.82.9.19'),

'14.63.160.219': Text(-0.047457773060320695, 0.655032585063581, '14.63.160.219')}

I want to change the IP address in the text object portion such that the file looks like this:

{'175.123.98.240': Text(-0.15349206308126684, -0.6696533109609498, 'xxx.123.98.240'),
 '54.66.152.105': Text(-1.0, -0.5455880938500245, 'xxx.66.152.105'),
 '62.97.116.82': Text(0.948676253595717, 0.6530664635187481, 'xxx.97.116.82'),
 '24.73.75.234': Text(0.849485905682265, -0.778703553136851, 'xxx.73.75.234'),
 '1.192.128.23': Text(0.2883091762715677, -0.03432011446968225, 'xxx.192.128.23'),
 '183.82.9.19': Text(-0.8855214994079628, 0.7201660238351776, 'xxx.82.9.19'),
 '14.63.160.219': Text(-0.047457773060320695, 0.655032585063581, 'xxx.63.160.219')}

This file is used for printing labels on a networkx graph.

I have a couple of questions.

1. Can the contents of a text object be modified?
2. If so, can it be changed without iterating through the file since the number of changes could range from 3 to 6,000, depending on what I am graphing?
3. How would I do it?

I did consider changing the IP address before I created my node and edge files but that resulted in separate IP address being clustered incorrectly. For example: 173.6.48.24 and 1.6.48.24 would both be converted to xxx.6.48.24.

Changing the IP address at the time of printing the labels seems like the only sensible method.

I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I have never dealt with text objects and I am out of my depth on this one.

Thanks

**Additional information**

The original data set is a list of IP addresses that have attack several honeypots I am running. I have taken the data and catalogued the data based on certain attack criteria.

The data that I showed was just one of the small attack networks. The label file was generated using the code:

labels = nx.draw_networkx_labels(compX, pos=pos_df)

Where compX is the file containing the data to be graphed and pos_df is the layout of the graph. In this case, I used nx.spring_layout().

I can display the contents of the label file using:

for k,v in labels.items():

```
    print(v)
```

However, “v” contains the text object, which I do not seem to be able to work with. The content of “v” is a follows:

Text(-0.15349206308126684, -0.6696533109609498, '175.123.98.240')
Text(-1.0, -0.5455880938500245, '54.66.152.105')
Text(0.948676253595717, 0.6530664635187481, '62.97.116.82')
Text(0.849485905682265, -0.778703553136851, '24.73.75.234')
Text(0.2883091762715677, -0.03432011446968225, '1.192.128.23')
Text(-0.8855214994079628, 0.7201660238351776, '183.82.9.19')
Text(-0.047457773060320695, 0.655032585063581, '14.63.160.219')

This is where I am stuck. I do not seem to be able to come up with any code that does not return some kind of “'Text' object has no attribute xxxx”.

As for replacing the first octet, I have the following code that works on a dataframe and I have just been experimenting to see if I can adapt it but so far, no luck:

df[column_ID] = df[column_ID].apply(lambda x: "xxx."+".".join(x.split('.')[1:4])) # Replace First octet

As I said, I would prefer not to iterate through the file. This cluster has seven entries; others can contain up to 6,000 nodes – granted the graph looks like a hairball with this many nodes, but most are between 3 and 25 nodes. I have a total of 60 clusters and as I collect more information, this number will rise.

Comment: Hi, can you share the code you tried? Where do those `Text` object come?

Comment: I found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to replacing text inside a text object:
1) Convert text object to string
2) Find the position to be changed and make the change
3) Use set_text() to make the change to the text object

**Example code**
        # Anonymize Source IP address
        for k,v in labels.items():
            a = str(v)
            a = a[a.find(", '"):]
            a = 'xxx' + a[a.find("."):][:-2]
            v.set_text(a)